# Background image size won't stay 100% height

Tags: css, image

I have got so far on the background of my new website and now i am stuck, the background image goes less than 100% height if you shrink the browser window.

I want it to stay full size and if you shrink it, I don't want the height to go any less than 100% (showing white)

Code here http://www.bestlincs.co.uk/new/

Comment: Do you actually want it to cover the whole screen? If that's the case, you need to use background-size:cover.

Comment: yes that maybe the case, but these are slider images and img tags not background tags :-(

Comment: Remove img tag, and make the images to be background of the slider :)

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code here. If you fix your code at that link, this question becomes useless to the community at large.

Answer (score 2):

you can use below code:

```
html or .classname { 
  background: url(ImageUrlhere) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: whenever i put  no-repeat center center fixed the images aren't there

Comment: Because you need height :) Add height to them :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

and set the background-size property to `cover`: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: no, the point is that if you shrink the browser window down so much the height of the image goes less than 100% and shows white, I want it to stay covered

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have not defined a height to the image give it a height 100% and it works i tried it in my browser and works fine

Comment: i'm using min height in css

Comment: @Lee YOUR LINK DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your needs - one way would be to specify a min-width and min-height attributes in css instead of pure width. As it will scale to whatever size it needs, then position it fixed to the top left corner (mind you, any "overflow" on the right will be cut off).

Source:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

A detailed explanation of your problem:
If you set an image to 100% width of its container and do not specify a height, it will always be stretched until it fills out the container, while the height is scaled to keep the image's aspect ratio.

E.g: Take an image that is 200px x 100px large, put it into a 300px wide container with it's width set to 100%. It will be scaled by a factor of 300/200 = 1.5 along both dimension, resulting in an image sized: 300px x 150px.
What will happen, if your image has a different aspect ratio than the user's screen? It will simply stretch to full width, then leave the rest blank. Setting a height as well would introduce even more problems, as your image would get distorted.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
body { 
  margin:0;
  background: url(image.gif) no-repeat; 
  padding: 0;
}
```

Then the background size will be 100%